# Method FiFo in Excel

Tags: excel, fifo

I have the following table (for example)

```
Product Quantity    Price
A            20         3
B             3         2
A           -10       3.1
A            -3       3.2
B            -1       2.2
```

Data is shown in time ascending sort and quantity which is negative means it is sold and if positive is bought amount.

What I want to do is to calculate realized and unrealized profit or loss for each product using "First in First out" method.

I tried a lot to write it with sumproduct combined with an array function but it does not work properly.

As I am really new in Excel world I would kindly ask you to give any hint how I can proceed further.

Bestie,
Jeyhun

Comment: You will be probably need vba

Comment: What are your expected results?  For example, using A, do you mean 20*3 (loss), 10*3.1 (profit), and 3*3.2 (profit) = 20*-3 + 10*3.1 + 3*3.2 = -60+31+9.6 = -19.4 meaning that there is a net loss of 19.4 on product A.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @tigeravatar with FIFO the profit is realized on sale of object based on the price of the first item cost till the pool or bucket is exhausted then it move to the next price, so in this instance the realized profit is for `B` is `0.2` and the currrent unrealized is `0.4`.  A is trickier Realized is `10*.1+3*.2=1.6` and unrealized is `7*2=1.4`.  At least that is how I understand FIFO.

Comment: Scott, you got it exactly in the way i perceived this definition. Thank you. I thought there is an easy way to do it in excel by using an array function. I will try to come up with VBA code and I will share it here later.